# What are the differences between pino-debug and express-pino-logger

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use `pino` for the existing debug library but I am not able to understand what are the differences between `pino-debug` and `express-pino-logger`.

And  How I can implement on the programmatic level. If anyone has already implemented it, please give me the solution.